# How to add empty rows to a data frame?

Tags: r

I am creating data.frames with by_group.
Now the number of rows depends on the dataset. Some have more rows than others. 
But i always need the same number.
Is there a more efficient way for doubling the dataset by adding the same number of rows, but with empty values?

```
#add empty rows to dataframe

library(dplyr)

var1 <- 1:10
var2 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0)
var3 <- rep(3, 10)

dat <- data.frame (var1, var2, var3)
View(dat)


dat2 <- data.frame (var1=rep(NA, 10), var2=rep(NA, 10), var3=rep(NA, 10))
bind_rows(dat, dat2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should allow you to double the number of rows by creating a matrix that has the same number of columns and rows as the original data frame, giving it the same names as the original data frame, then binding the rows.

```
library(dplyr)

var1 <- 1:10
var2 <- c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0)
var3 <- rep(3, 10)

dat <- data.frame (var1, var2, var3)

dat2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(dat), ncol = ncol(dat)))

names(dat2) <- names(dat)

bind_rows(dat, dat2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work

```
dat[ NROW(dat)+ NROW(dat),] <- NA
```

Assuming you want to double the rows of dataframe dat and assign additional rows with NA.